# Kivy - Using the "on_release" event in parent Widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I'm currently trying to trigger the "on_release" event of a custom button nested in a dynamic class. To be more specific. This is an example kv file of my current implementation:

```
#:kivy 1.10.1
#:include gui/components.kv

<MiddleSectionMain@AnchorLayout>:
    anchor_x: 'center'
    anchor_y: 'center'

    lb_text: ''
    text: spinner_1.text
    stateb1: button_1.state 

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        Label:
            text: root.lb_text
            size_hint_x: 0.3
        Spinner:
            id: spinner_1
            text: 'Select'
        IconButtonSmall:
            id: button_1
            icon_source: 'icons/add_32.png'
        IconButtonSmall:
            id: button_2
            icon_source: 'icons/edit_32.png'


<MainScreen>:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    Label:
        font_size: 25
        text: "Headline"

    GridLayout:
        cols: 1

        MiddleSectionMain:
            lb_text: "Label"
            on_stateb1: 
                if self.stateb1 == 'normal': app.root.current = 'Screen2'

        MiddleSectionMain:
            lb_text: "Label"
```

IconButtonSmall is defined in another .kv file (gui/components.kv).

This implementation works but I'm not really happy with it as buttons also provide the "on_release" event. So I wander if theres a way to use the "on_release" event instead of my version using "on_state" together with checking the current state.

Best,
Julz

Comment: Are you asking how to make the `MiddleSectionMain` have button-like behavior? Or how to change to `Screen2` from your `IconButtonSmall`s?

Comment: Hi, I want to change to different screens depending on which of the two IconButtonSmall was pressed (an "add" screen which will we Screen2, and an "edit" screen (not shown here)). I think ikolims answer will do exactly what I wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Assumption - Using `on_release` or `on_press` event to switch screen

The following example illustrates how to use `Button`'s event, `on_release` in a dynamic class to switch screen.

***Note:***
*If you want to use `on_press` event, replace `on_release` with `on_press`*

1. Declare StringProperty for each buttons e.g. `btn1_screen_name: ''`
2. Implement `on_release:` event for each buttons
3. Initialize `btn1_screen_name: 'Screen2'`

### Snippets

```
<MiddleSectionMain@AnchorLayout>:
    btn1_screen_name: ''
    btn2_screen_name: ''
    ...
    BoxLayout:
        IconButtonSmall:
            id: button_1
            icon_source: 'icons/add_32.png'
            on_release: app.root.current = root.btn1_screen_name
        IconButtonSmall:
            id: button_2
            icon_source: 'icons/edit_32.png'
            on_release: app.root.current = root.btn2_screen_name


<MainScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        ...
        GridLayout:
            cols: 1

            MiddleSectionMain:
                lb_text: "Label"
                btn1_screen_name: 'Screen2'
                btn2_screen_name: 'MainScreen'

            MiddleSectionMain:
                lb_text: "Label"
                btn1_screen_name: 'Screen3'
                btn2_screen_name: 'MainScreen'
```

Comment: Thank you once again :)